# Are PHP resource IDs unique?

Tags: php

Are PHP resource IDs unique per PHP instance? Does casting all kinds of resources to string returns "Resource id #X" (where `X` is some decimal number)? Is there a function that returns resource ID (I know about [`get_resource_type()`](http://php.net/get_resource_type) to get resource typem, but didn't find anything like `get_resouce_id()`), or does it have to be done like this?

```
function get_resource_id($resource)
{
    return is_resource($resouce) 
           ? substr((string) $resource, 13 /* strlen("Resource id #") */)
           : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the structure of "Resource id #1" - The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) does state: "Do not rely upon this structure; it is subject to change.", so your method to get the ID is not to be recommended.

Comment: @w3d Unfortunately, I do not know about any better (other) method to get the ID. Do you?

Comment: Sorry no, not really! Other than may be validating that you do actually get a numeric string returned and if not then try another method to get the ID eg. explode() on the '#' and get the 2nd element (if it exists) etc. Is the returned string solely dependent on (the version of) PHP? Or is it possible that the resource itself can influence what happens during casting?! TBH, if it's just PHP then you'll probably be pretty safe I would have thought... for now!? If you are just after a unique Id then you could just use the whole string, or _hash_ it may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jakub, yes PHP will always give you a unique ID for every resource that's currently in use. When a resource is unset() or free'd such as [mysql_free_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php). Then that ID is available again and PHP could reuse these resources again.

Be wary if you're "caching" or keeping resource ID's in the session and reusing them because PHP may free a resource, then recreate a new resource with that ID and your old resource ID might be pointing to something new.

So there you have it, resources are unique, but not forever!

Hope this helps demystify resource types in PHP for you.

Comment: Is it not possible that in certain environments 2 different users could get the _same_ resource ID when connecting to the same (shared) resource? Or is that impossible?

Answer (score 6):

Easy as it seams

```
intval($resource)
```